# Access violation writing location 0xaaaaaaaa

Tags: c++

This is my current code of the class Score in the `Score.h` file:-

```
class Score
{

protected:
long m_Scores;
long m_HighScore;
//private:

public:
Score();
~Score();
void Init();
void Update(float deltaMS);
void Render();
void Release();
void SetScore(long sc){
    m_Scores=sc;
}

long GetScore(){
    return m_Scores;
}
void SetHighScore(long sc){
    m_HighScore=sc;
}

long GetHighScore(){
    return m_HighScore;
}
void AddScore(int add);

};
```

I am getting the following error whenever I try to access m_Scores in the class itself.

```
Access violation writing location 0xaaaaaaaa.
```

The `SetScore()` method can't be run due to this.
I know I am doing something silly, but couldn't figure it out. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Without code making use of the class your question can't be answered.

Comment: I am just calling SetScore() method.

Comment: As @sharptooth says, the code posted looks fine but there is likely an interaction with the code using the class.

Comment: @Creator, that still isn't enough information. Is your code literally just a main function that creates a Score, calls SetScore() and then exits?

Comment: @Creator: Before you call a method you should instantiate an object. Code doing that is likely wrong and there lies the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The object was not created, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your `Score` object that you try to SetScore() is already outdated, destoryed. Pay attention to its lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was actually using a wrong condition to create the object. It's solved now.

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently accessing the class through a pointer, and the memory at the `pointer's` location has the value `0xaaaaaaaa`.  This looks a lot like a value that uninitialised memory would have.

So I guess you have a `Score *` variable that you are not filling in with something.  You need to do one of

- change it to `Score`, and use direct member access (`.`) instead of pointer indirection (`->`)
- initalise the variable with `var = new Score();` and later free it with `free var;`